# CodeIgniter: Controller structure for forms with many inputs

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

I'm developing a site using CodeIgniter and am trying to adhere to the "Fat Model / Skinny Controller" paradigm, but am running into some problems when it comes to pages containing forms with a number of inputs.  The code below is what I'm using to define the inputs for the address fields

Part of my Controller (where I'm defining the form inputs and their attributes):

```
$this->data['address1'] = array(
            'name' => 'address1',
            'id' => 'address1',
            'type' => 'text',
            'class' => 'field text addr',
            'tabindex' => '10',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('address1'),
            'placeholder' => 'Street Address'
        );

$this->data['address2'] = array(
            'name' => 'address2',
            'id' => 'address2',
            'type' => 'text',
            'class' => 'field text addr',
            'tabindex' => '11',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('address2'),
            'placeholder' => 'Address Line 2',
        );

$this->data['city'] = array(
            'name' => 'city',
            'id' => 'city',
            'type' => 'text',
            'class' => 'field text addr',
            'tabindex' => '12',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('city'),
            'placeholder' => 'City'
            );

$this->data['state'] = array(
            'name' => 'state',
            'id' => 'state',
            'class' => 'field addr',
            'tabindex' => '13',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('state'),
            'label' => array('class' => 'desc')
            );

$this->data['zip'] = array(
            'name' => 'zip',
            'id' => 'zip',
            'type' => 'text',
            'class' => 'field text addr',
            'tabindex' => '14',
            'maxlength' => '20',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('zip'),
            'placeholder' => 'Zip / Postal Code'
            );

$this->data['country'] = array(
            'name' => 'country',
            'id' => 'country',
            'class' => 'field addr',
            'tabindex' => '15',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('country')
            );
```

Part of my View (minus all the HTML to position the form inputs):

```
<?php
    echo form_open("address/add");
    echo form_input($address1);
    echo form_input($address2);
    echo form_input($city);

    $options = array();
    $options[''] = 'State / Province / Region';
    foreach($province_options AS $prov)
    {
            $options[$prov->id] = $prov->province;
    }
    echo form_dropdown('state',$options,'',$state);

    echo form_input($zip);

    $options = array();
    $options[''] = 'Country';
    foreach($country_options AS $cnt)
    {
            $options[$cnt->id] = $cnt->country;
    }
    echo form_dropdown('country',$options,'',$country);
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit & Continue');
    echo form_close();
?>
```

I feel like my Controller is overly verbose, but I can't think of what the alternative would be for how to organize the information necessary to represent my form if I'm planning on using the Form Helper to generate the form inputs in my view.  Is this the right way to be doing things, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little bit of logic that can be moved to the controller or even model layer:

```
$options = array();
$options[''] = 'Country';
foreach($country_options AS $cnt)
{
        $options[$cnt->id] = $cnt->country;
}
echo form_dropdown('country',$options,'',$country);
```

Could probably look like:

```
echo form_dropdown('country', $countries, '', $country);
```

...if you move the options to the controller or view.

This is a problem I run into all the time trying to keep things [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as possible, where to define the form data? I think sometimes we forget the power of the "V" in "MVC". You *could* define all the view logic in the view instead.

Things like `id`, `tabindex` and `placeholder` are only necessary and useful in the view. Things like form validation rules and data checking/prepping belong in the Controller/Model layer.

The form helper functions are useful, but sometimes raw HTML is better. For example:

```
// Controller
$this->data['address1'] = array(
            'name' => 'address1',
            'id' => 'address1',
            'type' => 'text',
            'class' => 'field text addr',
            'tabindex' => '10',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('address1'),
            'placeholder' => 'Street Address'
        );
// View
echo form_input($address1);
```

Or simply:

```
<input name="address1" id="address1" tabindex="10" type="text" placeholder="Street Address" value="<?php echo set_value('address1'); ?>" class="field text addr">
```

I wrote a bunch of applications last year where I defined all this stuff in the Model, and now I'm regretting it as I've been going back to do maintenance on them and all the view logic is obscured away in the Model or Controller. Editing a Controller or Model to change a `class` attribute is just silly.

Answer (score 2):

Just because Codeigniter provides all of these helpers does not mean you have to use them!

All you need is `form_open()` because this adds the CRSF token (if used).

Raw HTML is much cleaner and I suspect much faster than waiting for PHP to render markup.

**Edit:** *I would like to add, the reason its cleaner is because you have control over the output, where as CI might adere to certain specifications.*

I don't see a problem in your question.

**This is just silly**

```
$options = array();
$options[''] = 'State / Province / Region';
```

Comment: +1 for raw HTML (I was just posting a similar answer 30 minutes ago until dinner interrupted me), but I don't see what's "silly" about the code block you posted. Can you explain?

Comment: @MadM To answer your question I personally dont see the point in typecasting a var , then filling it with values, this might be ok inside a class, however this is a tmp array inside a method (BTW thank you PHP6 or 5.4 whatevers), the approach may be sound but for the sake of readability I think its wrong.

Comment: Well, without the *second* `$options = array();` the values from the first one would spill over (probably should use a different var name). I understand your meaning, but I still think it's good practice and makes it very clear what's going on to avoid "accidents".

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Both yours and Madmartigan's suggestions make a lot more sense for maintainability and flexibility of my site.